# How do I construct this triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I was trying to draw the following triangle in `latex tikz` and I just could not find a way to do it with respect to the given conditions.
[image]

1. Is it possible to construct it without trigonometry or analytical geometry?
2. Is it possible to show that it cannot be done without trigonometry or analytical geometry?
3. (Regrettably) I tried to do it via solving some trigonometrical equations, then I realized I am getting nowhere. So, how would I approach with trigonometry?

Note 1: In the actual drawing, $c=6$, but that does not matter, obviously.
Note 2: I am not looking for `LaTeX` help.

Comment: What concrete is given in the exercise?

Comment: Are you looking for $\LaTeX$ help or geometrical help such as $\psi = 60^\circ-\phi$

Comment: And $$\angle {CEB}=120^{\circ}$$

Comment: @Henry Yes, Ican see all thse, buıt those do not help to draw the triangle with *all the conditions met.*

Comment: "figure not to scale"...

Comment: Playing with this, I suspect that it cannot be constructed unless $\phi \lt 0$

Answer (score 5):

As noted in the comments, a little angle-chasing shows that $\phi + \psi = 60^\circ$. As a result, we can find $A^\prime$ on $\overline{BC}$ such that $\triangle ABE\cong \triangle A^\prime BE$, as shown:

[image]

Now, recall that, in a triangle, smaller angles are opposite smaller sides.

$$\begin{align}
\triangle ABE: \quad 60^\circ - \phi < 60^\circ &\quad\implies\quad p < q \\ 
\triangle A^\prime CE: \quad \phantom{60^\circ-\;}\phi < 60^\circ &\quad\implies\quad p < r
\end{align}$$

Consequently, $2p < q + r$, which contradicts the desired condition. $\square$

Answer (score 3):

This triangle cannot be constructed for any $\phi$. If we assume $\phi$ can be any value and still have the triangle be constructed, we can see that length $BE = 2 \cdot a$ as $\phi \to 60^\circ$. Then applying the sine rule on lengths BE and AE gives: $$\frac{2\cdot a}{\sin{(\phi + 60^\circ)}}=\frac{a}{\sin{(60^\circ - \phi)}}$$
For which the only solutions are $a=0$ (invalid) or $\phi = 30^\circ$. If $\phi = 30^\circ$, then length $AB =\sqrt{3} \cdot a$ by the sine rule and we are left with a right angled triangle ABC. By Pythagoras' we then have $AB^2+BC^2=AC^2$ which is not true with the given lengths - a contradiction. So there is no way to construct the given triangle.